# paper, scissors, stone how to display right result?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to use windows form to create a paper, scissors, stone game.
click a button1 to start show pictureBox1.
then click button2 to show Scissor in pictureBox2, and stop pictureBox1.

if picture1 is Scissor, the label will show "Tie".
if picture1 is Stone, show "You lose".
if picture1 is Paper, show "You win".

but the result is wrong.

Scissor show "You lose".
Stone show "Tie".
Paper show "You win".

```
    private int state = 1;
    public Exam5()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (state == 1)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("Scissor.jpg");
            pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
        }
        else if (state == 2)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("Stone.jpg");
            pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
        }
        else
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("Papper.jpg");
            pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
        }
        state++;
        if (state > 3) state = 1;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("Scissor.jpg");
        pictureBox2.Image = bitmap;

        if (state == 1) label1.Text = "Tie";
        else if (state == 2) label1.Text = "You lose";
        else label1.Text = "You win";
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("Stone.jpg");
        pictureBox2.Image = bitmap;
        timer1.Enabled = false;

        if (state == 1) label1.Text = "You win";
        else if (state == 2) label1.Text = "Tie";
        else label1.Text = "You lose";
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("Papper.jpg");
        pictureBox2.Image = bitmap;
        timer1.Enabled = false;

        if (state == 1) label1.Text = "You lose";
        else if (state == 2) label1.Text = "You win";
        else label1.Text = "Tie";
    }
```

Comment: I don't get the goal of the timer for this game? Where and how do you set it up?

Comment: You've got the line 'state++' so when it's state '1' and you show scissor, it then increments so state = 2, the shows the state '2' message "You lose!";

Comment: Increment state *before* you select the bitmap so the value matches the bitmap.  Disposing the old bitmap is not optional.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, note this is untested code, just quickly knocked it up on the fly, but should give you enough of an idea?

```
private int state = 1;
public Exam5()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = true;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedImage;

    state++;

    if (state > 3) state = 1;

    switch (state)
    {
        case 1: 
            selectedImage = "Scissor.jpg";
            break;

        case 1: 
            selectedImage = "Stone.jpg";
            break;

        case 1: 
            selectedImage = "Paper.jpg";
            break;
    }

    pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(selectedImage);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = false;
    pictureBox2.Image = new Bitmap("Scissor.jpg");

    if (state == 1) 
        label1.Text = "Tie";
    else if (state == 2) 
        label1.Text = "You lose";
    else 
        label1.Text = "You win";
}
```